# How can I read URLs on separate lines in a .txt file and ping each one

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a `.txt` file with 5 urls in it. I want to read it line by line, and perform 4 ping requests for each site, and extract the time. The code I wrote is below, but it isn't working.

Can anyone give me a hint?

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /home/akis/Desktop/sites.txt
declare -i var=1
while read -r line
do
    while $var <= 5 
    do
        var2=$((var2+1)) 
        name="$line" | ping -c 4 $name > $var.txt | awk '{ print $8 }' < $var.txt | awk '/time/' > $var2.txt | tr '=' '\t' < $var2.txt | awk '{ print $2 }' > $var2.txt
    done

    var=$((var+1))  
done
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<sup>This as well as [Sergiy's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/975923/507051) came from [Loop over text file with URLs and execute ping on each](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975367/loop-over-text-file-with-urls-and-execute-ping-on-each).</sup>

Assuming the file `urls` resides in the current directory and contains your urls **only**, one per line:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r l || [ -n "$l" ]; do
  avg=$(ping -q -w 10 "$l" | sed '$!d;s_.*=[^/]*/\([^/]*\)/.*_\1_')
  echo "Average respond time for $l: $avg ms" >> avg_time
done < "urls"
```

#### Example run

Above script was named `avg` here.

```
$ cat urls
askubuntu.com
unix.stackexchange.com
stackoverflow.com
$ ./avg
$ cat avg_time 
Average respond time for askubuntu.com: 37.742 ms
Average respond time for unix.stackexchange.com: 35.966 ms
Average respond time for stackoverflow.com: 38.982 ms
```

#### Explanations

- `#!/bin/bash`
  this so-called [*shebang*](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/basics#the_shebang) defines which shell your script has to be started with, here it's [`bash`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/basicgrammar)
- `while IFS='' read -r l || [ -n "$l" ]; do stuff; done < "urls"`
  [`read`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read) the file named `urls` line by line, assigning the content of the currently processed line to variable `l` and doing **`stuff`** with it
- `ping -q -w 10 "$l"` (= `ping -qw10 "$l"`)
  call `ping` with the content of variable `l` as the argument and the options `-q`uiet (less output we don't need) and `-w 10` (timeout in seconds), so that the currently processed URL is pinged for exactly `10` seconds  – you may adjust this value to your needs as well as specify other options (see [`man ping`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ping.1.html)) for the list)
- `avg=$(ping … | sed …)`
  pipe the output of `ping` to `sed` which cuts out the average respond time and save this value in variable `avg`

  - `sed '$!d;s_.*=[^/]*/\([^/]*\)/.*_\1_'`
  - `sed '$!d`
    don't (`!`) `d`elete the last line (`$`), but the whole rest
  - `sed 's/a/b/'`
    `s`ubstitute `a` by `b` – can also be written as e.g. `sed 's_a_b_'` if useful, this way we don't need to escape literal slash characters in the strings

    - `.*` – take everything
    - `=` and `/` – a literal “=” and “/”
    - `[^/]*` – take everything that's not (`^`) a slash
    - `\([^/]*\)` – take everything that's not (`^`) a slash and save it in a group
    - `\1` – the first group saved with `\(…\)` before
  - the same work could also be done with `awk -F/ '/^rtt/{print$5}'`:

    - `-F/` – define `/` as the `F`ield delimiter
    - `/^rtt/{…}` – select the line beginning (`^`) with “rtt” and do `…` with it
    - `print$5` – `print` only field no. `5`
- `echo "Average respond time for $l: $avg ms" >> avg_time`
  print the text inserting the content of the variables `l` and `avg` and redirect this output to the file `avg_time` appending to its content

Comment: can you please give me some further explanation about this  part of the code? sed '$!d;s_.*=[^/]*/\([^/]*\)/.*_\1_')

Comment: @AkisTachmatzidis My pleasure! I added detailed explanations for the `sed` expressions and an `awk` alternative as well. You're welcome to meet me in [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69125/discussion-between-akis-tachmatzidis-and-dessert) for further explanations or other help.

Answer (score 7):

For a single simple command such as `ping` , one can use `xargs`. The cool thing about `xargs` is that it has `--arg-file` option which allows you to specify file which `xargs` will use to provide positional parameters to the command you're trying to run; in your case, that would be one site per line in the text file.

Specifically the command you want is this:

```
xargs -I% --arg-file=./input.txt  ping -c 4 %
```

- `-I` allows us to choose place holder for each argument, which `xargs` internally will
- `--arg-file` is the file from which positional parameters will come from; note that we're using `./` to indicate that the file is located in current working directory
- `ping -c 4` will attempt to `ping` each site that comes from `input.txt` with 4 packets

Note that we can also use `-q` option to `ping` that will prevent printing a line for each packet received/transmitted, with only statistics being outputted. From there we can clean up output even further with `awk` or any other text-processing utility (keep in mind that output will be buffered while going via pipe and waiting for `ping` to actually finish and output statistics, so will show up on the screen a bit slow):

```
$ xargs -I% --arg-file=./input.txt  ping -c 4 % -q | awk '/^---/||/avg/'                                                                                     
--- askubuntu.com ping statistics ---
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 49.677/73.403/94.312/19.276 ms
--- unix.stackexchange.com ping statistics ---
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 40.015/59.099/115.545/32.590 ms
--- stackoverflow.com ping statistics ---
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 40.130/40.878/42.685/1.056 ms

$ xargs -I% --arg-file=./input.txt  ping -c 4 % -q | awk -F'[ /]' '/^---/{print $2};/avg/{print $8}'                                                         
askubuntu.com
39.809
unix.stackexchange.com
189.557
stackoverflow.com
161.974
```